# Create instance of a class based on route name

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create new instance of class based on route name. It seems the subscribed solution is to use a Factory Provider. But the problem here is that declaring of providers is initialize first before route is called. Here's what I have

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import {InitializerComponent} from "./components/initializer.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path : 'category/:id', component: InitializerComponent},
        { path : 'product/:id', component: InitializerComponent}
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**my-factory.service.ts**

```
import {ProductService} from 'product.service';
import {CategoryService} from 'category.service'

let myFactoryService = (route_name) => {

    var my_services = {
        product : ProductService,
        category : CategoryService
    }

    return new my_services[route_name](dependencies here...);
};

export let MyServiceProvider =
  { provide: myDynamicService,
     useFactory: myFactoryService,
     deps: [some deps here...]
  };
```

Now using it in my component

**initializer.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MyServiceProvider } from 'my-factory.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'initializer-component',
    template: `
        <div>Create Instace of class based on route name</div>
    `,
    providers: [MyServiceProvider]
})

export class InitializerComponent {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        var self = this;

        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {

            // get route name here
            var route_name = this.route_name; // just sample code

            // create new instance of class here based on route name
            var my_service = new MyServiceProvider(route_name);

            // but providers is declared in the component how can we call the factory service here?
        });
    }
}
```

Is this possible in factory provider?

**EDIT:**
Problem here is how can I pass route name to MyServiceProvider to create dynamic instance of services?

Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: It isn't really clear what exactly is the problem here. Do you want to use MyServiceProvider inside InitializerComponent ? Inject it then.

Comment: @estus, Problem here is how can I pass route name to my MyServiceProvider if MyServiceProvider is declared @Component?

Comment: `this.route.pathFromRoot`, I guess. See ActivatedRoute reference, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html

Comment: thanks, but not the answer I'm looking for. MyServiceProvider create new instance of services based on the passed route to it. e.g new MyServiceProvider(product). Now this creates a new instance of Product Service.

Comment: You can extract `product` or `category` key name from pathFromRoot, can't you?